# postgres string to json

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table with col - fields.

Values can be '',NULL or string like - {"key":"value"}

while converting the string to json and accessing the object, I am getting below error:

Error - Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

I ran the below query:

`select to_json(field)->>'rest_uri' from dbo.tablename`

Answer (score 0):

PostrgeSQL needs a datatype to determine the type of **json** value, when we select from a table the column type is known so a *null* value is accepted.

> ```
> create table dbo_tablename (field varchar(25));
> insert into dbo_tablename values ('test'),(null);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select to_json(field) from dbo_tablename;
> ```
>
> ```
> | to_json |
> | :------ |
> | "test"  |
> | null    |
> ```

> ```
> select jsonb_agg(dbo_tablename)
> from dbo_tablename
> ```
>
> ```
> | jsonb_agg                            |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> | [{"field": "test"}, {"field": null}] |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b31ec1f1d1f2d6b33a5014a3d16d480a)*es_14&fiddle=e9edbef66da563358b847d828986808c)*